# Get meta information from post parent

Tags: post-meta

So I am in a single page and I want to get some meta information from a parent page. This code is inside my footer.php:

```
if (is_single()) {
    global $post;
    $parent = get_post_achestor ( $post->ID );
    $some_value = get_post_meta( $parent, 'some_metabox_param', true);
}
```

It's not working people, can you please have a look?

UPDATE: the parent page in question is template that has this loop

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&paged=1' ); 
if ( have_posts() ) : global $more; ?>              
<div class="items">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $more = 0; ?>
         <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: try to check what you get in `$parent` variable. `echo $parent;`

Comment: the echo is "array", that's all.

Comment: This shows array(0) { }

Comment: array(0){} means, this post has no meta data. make you sure you $post->ID is not empty

Comment: Never ever use query_posts. And if you have to, use reset_postdata after your loop...

Comment: get_post_achestor() is not a Wordpress function. Are you sure this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The ID of the parent post is in `$post->post_parent`. When a post has no parent, that number is `0`. So …

```
if ( is_singular() ) 
{
    global $post;
    if ( 0 !== (int) $post->post_parent )
    {
        $some_value = get_post_meta( $post->post_parent, 'some_metabox_param', true );
        if ( ! empty ( $some_value ) )
            echo $some_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. The parent page I am trying to get the meta info from is a custom page with a loop built with query_posts(), maybe this shed some light?

Comment: A page (post) is an object, not a loop.

Comment: I've updated the question, please check :)